# How to set the longitude and latitude from ViewModel in bing maps in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want to give the longitude and latitude from ViewModel.

Now i am using like:-

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pushpin p = new Pushpin();
        p.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        p.Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude.Text), double.Parse(latitude.Text));//Longitude and Latitude
        p.Content = "I'm here";//To show the place where it is located
        map1.Children.Add(p);
        map1.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude.Text), double.Parse(latitude.Text), 200), 9);
    }
```

My Xaml is:-

```
  <Grid x:Name="MapPageUIContainer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0">
        <my:Map CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" CredentialsProvider=""  Mode="AerialWithLabels" Height="543" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="2,100,0,0"  />
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" Background="#FFA3A371">
            <TextBlock Text="Map Example" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,627,0,0" Name="longitude" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,627,0,0" Name="latitude" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <Button Content="Set" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,690,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

Here i want to give the Pushpin, longitude, latitude from view model. Please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

I have try like this..

```
public class MapPageViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    public static string _longitude;
    public string longitude
    {
        get { return _longitude; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.longitude, value); }
    }

    public static string _latitude;
    public string latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.latitude, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveAsyncCommand setButton { get; set; }

    public MapPageViewModel()
    {
        setButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
        setButton.Subscribe(x => {

            Pushpin p = new Pushpin();
            p.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            p.Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude), double.Parse(latitude));
            p.Content = "I'm here";//To show the place where it is located
            //map1.Children.Add(p);
            //map1.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude), double.Parse(latitude), 200), 9);
        });
    }


}
```

But i don't know how to set map1.Children.Add() and map1.SetView and how to bind these values in Map?

Hi Clemens. I have tried your instruction. But it showing error.

[image: Screen shot of error message]

And also i have try this:-

```
public MapPageViewModel()
    {
        PushpinItems = new ObservableCollection<PushpinItem>();
        PushpinItem pp = new PushpinItem();
        setButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
        setButton.Subscribe(x => {
            pp.Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude), double.Parse(latitude));
            pp.Text = "I'm here";
            PushpinItems.Add(pp);
        });
    }
```

But here run time error happening. Please let me know where i did mistake.

Comment: In the second approach you also have to create the new PushpinItem object *inside* the Subscribe handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a proper MVVM approach you would usually have a `MapItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` for the Pushpin, and bind that to an `ObservableCollection` of pushpin data items in your view model:

```
public class PushpinItem
{
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MapPageViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<PushpinItem> PushpinItems { get; set; }
    ...

    public MapPageViewModel()
    {
        PushpinItems = new ObservableCollection<PushpinItem>();
        setButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();

        setButton.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            PushpinItems.Add(new PushpinItem
            {
                Location = new GeoCoordinate(...),
                Text = ...
            });
        });
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<map:Map ...>
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinItems}">
        <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <map:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Text}"
                             Background="Yellow" Foreground="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </map:MapItemsControl>
</map:Map>
```

Comment: Hi @Clemens. I have follow your instruction. But it showing error message to me. Herewith i have attached the screen shot. Please let me know what mistake i did?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There has to be a comma instead of a semicolon. And please note that this is only one possible way of writing the code. You may as well first create the PushpinItem object, then set the Location and Text properties, and finally add it to the PushpinItems list.

Comment: For some reason StackOverflow doesn't allow me to edit my own answer. I'll try again later.

Comment: I have already tried with comma. But error was raised at run time. Can you send me the edited code to my mail? If it is possible please send me. **vijaydhascr@gmail.com**

Comment: Just use the other approach you've shown in your updated question, and create new PushpinItem objects inside the Subscrive handler.

Comment: But i am facing error on this line. **pp.Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude), double.Parse(latitude));**  The error message is:- _An OnError occurred on an object (usually ObservableAsPropertyHelper) that would break a binding or command. To prevent this, Subscribe to the ThrownExceptions property of your objects_.

Comment: Well, I've tested this example with the Bing Maps Control for Silverlight, which afaik is slightly different from the Windows Phone version. In my example I used the type `Location` for the Location property, but assigned a new instance of type `GeoCoordinate`. You may also have to change the Location property type to `GeoCoordinate` in the PushpinItem class. And did you actually move the `PushpinItem pp = new PushpinItem();` line to inside the Subscribe handler?

Comment: Hi @Clemens.. I have already changed into GeoCoordinate. Yes I have move the instance to Subscribe. Till now that same line getting error.

Comment: Hi @Clemens [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxedZzp29FnBOHRTYVlnWVc3ZFE/edit?usp=sharing] Here i attached the text files. Please review that. Please let me know any idea to solve this.

Comment: Did you try the other way round, and use Location instead of GeoCoordinate?

Comment: Yes @Clemens.. Now i am using GeoCoordinate only.

Comment: Hi @Clemens.. This is my mistake only. Now only i noticed that Both longitude and latitude value is empty. That's why only i am getting Error.. Now there is no error. And it's Working. But how to set the **map1.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(longitude), double.Parse(latitude), 200), 9);** I see some examples. In that examples they use center property for this setView. But i can not find that. Please let me know how to set the SetView. And post your final answer. This may help to others. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi @ Clemens.. Now i got another example and it's working for SetView.. [http://sveiberg.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/5/comment-page-1/#comment-6]. Thanks for your Valuable answer..

Answer (score 1):

[SetView From ViewModel](http://sveiberg.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/5/comment-page-1/#comment-6)
@Clemens and this link is very helpful to me..!! Thanks for Both of them..!!